# Module pattern error: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

This code works in JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/estevancarlos/w8yo3mp4/1/

```
let ScrollAnim = (function() {
    console.log('ScrollAnim loaded');

    this.init = function() {
        console.log('init loaded');
    };

    this.getScenes = function() {
        console.log('getScenes loaded');
    };

    return this;
})();

ScrollAnim.init();
ScrollAnim.getScenes();
```

However it **does not work** within my actual project, http://veve.io/wip2. I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'init' of undefined
```

I don't know what is causing this differentiation. Suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword Check the difference between let and var

Answer (score 2):

First of all this is **not** a module pattern. You are polluting global context with your functions.

On jsfiddle you are not using strict mode. And your IIFE is being called in `window` context. You can check your `ScrollAnim` is actually `window`. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w8yo3mp4/3/).

`console.log(ScrollAnim === window); //true`

Your actuall project is using `'use strict';` resulting in `this` to be `undefined`. Which in turn causes the error.

This is module pattern;

```
let ScrollAnim = (function() {
    console.log('ScrollAnim loaded');

    return {
      init: function() {
        console.log('init loaded');
      },

      getScenes: function() {
        console.log('getScenes loaded');
      }
    };
})();
```